# How to disable Textfield from using the auto-suggestion on IOS

Tags: codenameone

I'm using the contents of a Textfield for a search.

Since it's a search I don't want any auto-correct/auto-suggestions.
Both Android and IOS show suggestions (just above the keyboard) as I type.

Android will use whatever I type.
IOS (9.3.2) will use the highlighted suggestion even though I hit done on the keyboard (as opposed to clicking on the suggestion).

Should I be looking for a way to tell the keyboard to not show suggestions, or for the Textfield to ignore suggestions from the keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `TextField` constraint to `NON_PREDICTIVE` specifically:

```
myTextFieldOrTextArea.setConstraint(TextArea.NON_PREDICTIVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the *UITextfield* for which you desire to turn off auto correct, set the *setAutoCorrectionType* to *UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo*.